# $\sin x \sin(\pi/2-x)=\sin x \cos x $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

During a question involving proving a trigonometric identity, I was given help in which one of the lines showed that $\sin x \sin(\pi/2-x)$ equals $\sin x \cos x$? Could anyone please explain to me/show me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: sine and cosine graph]

The sine and cosine function are very closely related.  In fact, the one is just a horizontal shift of the other.

You have then that $\cos(x) = \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})$, which is seen by a horizontal shift to the right of the cosine function by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Furthermore, you have that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ due to the fact that the cosine function is even.  Thus, it follows that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)=\sin(-x+\frac{\pi}{2})$.

The identity then follows that $\sin(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Comment: Wow, that's a great.  I am a visual learner so seeing the differences between the graphs really helps.  I already knew this information, but I suppose I just never thought of it that way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is true because $\cos(\pi/2-x) = \sin x$. If you ask why this is true? to make thing easy for you to follow, assume $0 < x < \pi/2$, then you let $A = x, B = \pi/2 - x $, then $A, B$ are complimentary angles in a right $\triangle$, and using SOHCAHTOA you conclude that $\sin A = \cos B$.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! So the sin(pi/2-x)=sin(A-b), which then  you could use to implement into the equation with cosb =cosx